# How to use $document in a Modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having trouble using $document in the modals controller. Is there a correct way of passing it in? I cant use just document as our angular project rules do not allow it

Calling the modal

```
  var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: "errorsModal.html",
    controller: ["$uibModalInstance", "data","vm", modalController],
    controllerAs: "vm",
    size:"md",
    resolve: {
      data: function () {
        return referenceDataService.getErrors().$loaded();
      },
      vm: function (){
        return vm;
      }
    }
  });

}
```

Modals Function I am trying to use $document in

```
  function isTrueOrFalse(elementId,tickBoxElement,newData){
    console.log(vm.check);
    var checkBox = $document.getElementById(tickBoxElement);
    checkBox.checked = !checkBox.checked;
    updateErrors(newData,parentVm,true);

    if(checkBox.checked === true){
      checkBox.checked = false;
      updateErrors(newData,parentVm,true);
    }
    else if(checkBox.checked ===false){
      checkBox.checked = true;
      updateErrors(newData,parentVm,false);

    }
    else{
      checkBox.checked = true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: In my view it is an AngularJs version of document

Comment: So your using angular? You need to add the [tag:angular] tag then

Comment: yes it was my bad it wasn't included. i completely forgotten $document and such are angular. and not just standard

Comment: You have to add $document through dependency injection of angularjs

Comment: Nitesh Rana already done. all dependencies are injected and running, i am using $document earlier in the code, but as Modal uses a separate controller within a controller, i have had to bring in the parent scope separately. I'm unsure how to do it with $document

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found my own workaround using `angular.element("elementId")`